# Can repeated joins be done more efficiently across many tables?

Tags: python, pandas, inner-join, python-polars

I have a problem which involves performing an inner join over multiple tables containing potentially tens of millions of rows. I'm aware that this ordinarily can't be optimized much more than a standard join using something like pandas or polars, but I *think* there are some caveats to the situation which could allow a much more efficient solution - namely, that the tables are interrelated with one another.

Concretely, the tables are grid pairings, where a column contains indices indicating where a grid matches with another grid. So something that looks like this:

```
| A |  B   |
| - | ---- |
| 0 | 1, 2 |
| 1 | 4, 5 |
| 3 | 7    |
```

Would mean A[0] matches B[1] and B[2]; A[1] matches B[4] and B[5]; and A[3] matches B[7].

In reality I need to handle an arbitrary number of grids, but as an example let's say I have 3 grids - A, B, C - which leads to 3 tables / grid pairings (3C2 = [AB, AC, BC]):

```
| A |  B   |
| - | ---- |
| 0 | 1, 2 |
| 1 | 4, 5 |
| 3 | 7    |

| A |    C    |
| - | ------- |
| 0 | 1, 2, 3 |
| 1 | 2       |

| B |    C    |
| - | ------- |
| 1 | 1, 2    |
| 2 | 1, 2    |
| 5 | 1, 2, 3 |
```

The final result is then the inner join over all of these tables, which would look like:

```
| A |  B   |  C   |
| - | ---- | ---- |
| 0 | 1, 2 | 1, 2 |
| 1 | 5    | 2    |
```

Or, equivalently:

```
| A | B | C |
| - | - | - |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
```

This represents the indices that are simultaneously matched across all grids: A[0] matches B[1] matches C[1], etc.

The above example in python:

```python
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd 

def create_table(indices: dict, names: list) -> pd.MultiIndex:
    table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(indices, orient='index').stack().astype(int)
    index = table.reset_index().set_index(['level_0', 0]).index
    return index.set_names(names)
    
AB = create_table({
    0: [1, 2],
    1: [4, 5],
    3: [7],
}, ['A', 'B'])

AC = create_table({
    0: [1, 2, 3],
    1: [2],
}, ['A', 'C'])

BC = create_table({
    1: [1, 2],
    2: [1, 2],
    5: [1, 2, 3],
}, ['B', 'C'])

join   = lambda df1, df2: df1.join(df2, how='inner')
result = reduce(join, [AB, AC, BC]).reorder_levels(['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(result)
```

```
MultiIndex([(0, 1, 1),
            (0, 1, 2),
            (0, 2, 1),
            (0, 2, 2),
            (1, 5, 2)],
           names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

This works great, until I have several tables with millions of rows. If I don't enforce the global matching constraint, so that I use an 'anchor' grid to match against (A matches B; A matches C; don't check if B matches C) - I have a solution that can run in a few seconds with minimal memory requirements. Adding that B<=>C check in the general case however, requires more than an order of magnitude more resources since I now need to expand the inner lists.

The only way I can see that gets around that would be to keep the tables in the condensed format (allowing a list to be a column element) - but I would then need to somehow efficiently transpose the table in that condensed format, e.g.

```
| A |  B   |      | B |  A   |
| - | ---- |  =>  | - | ---- | 
| 0 | 1, 2 |      | 1 | 0, 1 |
| 1 | 1    |      | 2 | 0    |
```

And here is a polars solution which performs a more realistic stress test:

```python
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np 
import polars as pl 
import time

def create_table_pl(indices, names: list):
    c1 = np.repeat(np.arange(len(indices), dtype='int64'), list(map(len, indices)) )
    c2 = np.concatenate(indices).astype(dtype='int64')
    print(f'{names}: {len(c2):,} rows')
    return pl.DataFrame(dict(zip(names, [c1,c2]))).set_sorted(names[0]).lazy()

def match(grids): 
    """ Use a BallTree to find close elements between grids """
    return BallTree(grids[1][:, None], p=np.inf).query_radius(grids[0][:, None], 5)

# Previous example
# AB = create_table_pl([[1,2], [4,5], [], [7]], ['A', 'B'])
# AC = create_table_pl([[1,2,3], [2]], ['A', 'C'])
# BC = create_table_pl([[], [1,2], [1,2], [], [], [1,2,3]], ['B', 'C'])
# pairs = [AB, AC, BC]
# names = ['A','B','C']

n = 500000
grids = np.arange(n), np.arange(0,n,2), np.arange(0,n,3), np.arange(0,n,5)
names = list('abcd')
pairs = list(map(create_table_pl, map(match, combinations(grids, 2)), combinations(names, 2)))

start = time.time()
join  = lambda df1, df2: df1.join(df2, on=set(df2.columns).intersection(set(df1.columns)))
table = reduce(join, pairs).select(names).sort(names)

print(table.collect())
print(f'{time.time()-start:.2f} seconds')
```

```
('a', 'b'): 2,749,985 rows
('a', 'c'): 1,833,325 rows
('a', 'd'): 1,099,994 rows
('b', 'c'): 916,662 rows
('b', 'd'): 549,997 rows
('c', 'd'): 366,665 rows
shape: (11_183_244, 4)
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ a      ┆ b      ┆ c      ┆ d     │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ 0      ┆ 0      ┆ 0      ┆ 0     │
│ 0      ┆ 0      ┆ 0      ┆ 1     │
│ 0      ┆ 0      ┆ 1      ┆ 0     │
│ 0      ┆ 0      ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ …      ┆ …      ┆ …      ┆ …     │
│ 499999 ┆ 249998 ┆ 166665 ┆ 99999 │
│ 499999 ┆ 249998 ┆ 166666 ┆ 99999 │
│ 499999 ┆ 249999 ┆ 166665 ┆ 99999 │
│ 499999 ┆ 249999 ┆ 166666 ┆ 99999 │
└────────┴────────┴────────┴───────┘
1.66 seconds
```

Alternatively, this whole problem can be equivalently represented as a graph, where entries in the final table represent all cycles in the graph...but I'm not sure there are going to be any *more* efficient solutions down that path.

Answer (score 0):

polars doesn't have a multiindex so that isn't a feasible way to store data in polars. This seems to work although I'm not sure if it helps with scaling other than polars being faster and more efficient than pandas. I think you'd have to give more of a hint as to what the scale looks like. Is it millions of rows of ABCs or what?

Anyway, here it is:

```
import polars as pl


plAB=pl.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,3],'B':[[1,2],[4,5],[7]]})
plAC=pl.DataFrame({'A':[0,1],'C':[[1,2,3],[2]]})
plBC=pl.DataFrame({'B':[1,2,5],'C':[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2,3]]})


def alljoin(*dfs):
    """go through all dfs and join them sequentially"""
    for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
        df=df.explode([x for x,y in df.schema.items() if y==pl.List()])
        if i==0:
            progress=df
        else:
            progress = progress.join(df, 
                on=[x for x in df.columns if x in progress.columns])

    progress=progress.select(sorted(progress.columns))
    return progress
            
            
alljoin(plAB, plAC, plBC)

shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ 0   ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
│ 0   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 2   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much exactly the solution I have using polars as well but also using .lazy(). I was hoping there might be some way to recursively apply the inner join to the nested lists in some intelligent manner, but I think I need to change the representation somehow to avoid exploding the lists. 

As far as the scale, yes, potentially millions of rows with something on the order of 2 to 20 tables. Just ran an example which produces 3 tables: `[(1037575, 2), (3074387, 2), (1484742, 2)]: time=5.09 seconds  dMem=9.67 GB`.

Comment: The main issue is that the example above is only a single block out of 100 that the inner join is being run on, as I'm already partitioning my actual data and performing other work using dask. That's also using a toy dataset with grids of size [10, 1000, 1000], [50, 500, 500], and [300, 50, 50]; the data this is meant to run on will have more grids with larger dimension sizes.

Comment: If you have a lot of columns then you could defer explosions of all list columns (as I have above) and just explode the ones that will be used to join until it's necessary to join by them. You could arrange them to have the ones with columns in common together and only mash together ones with dissimilar columns later. Like if df1, df3, df5, df7 have [A, B] and df2, df4, df6, df10 have [B,C] then join all the odd numbered ones together, join all the evens together, and then join those 2 last.

Comment: Good idea, thanks for the suggestion! I tried it with a few different arrangements of explode/join, but the best solution I've found so far is to manually explode with numpy prior to the DataFrame creation. 

I've added my current implementation along with an example of a larger dataset.